# Why does clearInterval works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this example:

```
<p id="test"></p>

<button onClick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop time!</button>
<button onClick="setInterval(myTimer, 1000)">Start time!</button>

<script>

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

</script>
```

When I click "Stop time!" for the first time it works as it should, but after I click "Start time!" I cannot stop timer anymore. Why exactly is this happening and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this code

```
<button onClick="setInterval(myTimer, 1000)">Start time!</button>
```

It does not work because you do not set the new timer to the variable. It does not know the new value should be set there.

Not a fan of inline code, but this would work

```
<button onClick="myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)">Start time!</button>
```

A better design would be something like this:

```js
(function() {

  var timer;

  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  }

  function startTimer() {
    stopTimer(); //make sure timer is not already running
    timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000); //start new timer
  }

  function stopTimer() {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
  }

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopTimer);
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startTimer);

  startTimer();

}());
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>

<button id="stop">Stop time!</button>
<button id="start">Start time!</button>
```

Comment: I fail to understand why giving this value to a variable only works. Does it have to in variable and why?

Comment: Because the original variable holds the interval id that is returned. Setting a new interval has no relationship to the original time you called it.

Comment: Variable is not related to anything. There are no relationships here. The setInterval returns an numeric id that represents a reference to that interval. The JavaScript engine has no clue what you do with that interval that you return. You can store it ( like you do with myVar) or you can ignore it (like you do with the onclick). There is no relationship with calling a method and having it make an id. You can call the same interval 100s of times and they all generate an id, and not a single one of those intervals will be related to another. They are all separate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<p id="test"></p>

<button onClick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop time!</button>
<button onClick="startTimer()">Start time!</button>
<script>
var myVar;

function startTimer() {

    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>
```