# Function cannot be called more than once

Tags: javascript, function

StopBtn cannot be called twice

Once the function is called it remains same and doesnt functions and i also got an error saying Timer is not a object. I do not really know what the problem is

```
var timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);

function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "The Current time is > " + time;
}

var startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop");

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", stopTime);

function stopTime() {
  var stoptime = clearInterval(timer);
  console.log("Stop");
}

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startTime);

function startTime() {
  var starttime = setInterval(clock, 1000);
  console.log("hello");
}
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <button id="stop">STOP TIME</button>
  <button id="start">START TIME</button>
  <h1 id="h1">We are Coding JavaScript</h1>
  <h3>Keep On Practicing Dude!</h3>

  <div id="time"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does clearInterval works only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678652/why-does-clearinterval-works-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `startTime` function, you were setting up a new variable to associate with the timer. The `stopTime` function doesn't use that variable so it doesn't stop the timer after pressing the Start button.

Just re-use one variable throughout the code for the timer.

**NOTES:**

You've actually got a more complex solution than is needed. There's no need for a `clock()` function that starts the clock and a `startTime` function that calls the `clock` function since they both need to do the same thing.

Instead of using `setInterval()`, use `setTimeout` (which is a one-time timer), but place the timer inside of the `start` function so it becomes recursive.

Don't use .innerHTML when the string you are getting/setting doesn't contain any HTML because `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` when working with DOM element strings.

Only scan the DOM once for elements you're going to work with over and over.

```js
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop");
var clock = document.getElementById("currentTime");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startClock);
stopBtn.addEventListener("click", stopClock);

// This one variable will represent the timer
// throughout the code
var timer = null;

function startClock() {
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
  clock.textContent = "The Current time is > " + time;
  timer = setTimeout(startClock, 1000)
}

function stopClock() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  console.log("Stop");
}

startClock();
```

```html
<button id="stop">STOP TIME</button>
<button id="start">START TIME</button>
<div id="currentTime"></div>
```